# DotNetCoreCLI@2 Restore failing on all solutions today

Tags: azure-devops, dotnetcorecli

Starting today, all 28 of our Azure DevOps hosted .Net builds are failing on the nuget restore task.

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Restore
  inputs:
  command: restore
  projects: |
  $(BuildParameters.RestoreBuildProjects)
  $(BuildParameters.TestProjects)
  selectOrConfig: config
  nugetConfigPath: nuget.config

We have poked and prodded everything we can think of, but there's always just an extremely unhelpful message:   error MSB4181: The "RestoreTask" task returned false but did not log an error.

-Enabling System Diagnostics (no better err msgs)
-Changed to on-prem build agent(that worked but we can't leave it that way)

Comment: We are also seeing this issue, though not using Azure DevOps pipelines. Some people have had varying degrees of success/failure restoring from local machines but none reproduce this exact error.

Comment: @TheXenocide referenced this issue: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/12075